# Bind to a Service in Android

Tags: android, service

I have a question about services in Android. I want to know why it’s necessary for to bind the service, and doing a connection to it? I am doing an application with geolocation using a service wich implements the GPS module. And for getting the location I create a variable in the class static and public method static to be called from outside the class, and that is it.
To retrieve the position from the GPS I just used in my classes:

```
Location mLocation = ServiceGPS.getLocation();
```

The class ServiceGPS has this method:

```
public static Location getLocation(){
    return mLocation;
}
```

Then, why I need to used the bind service?
Thanks a lot for your help, and sharing your knowledge with me.

BR.
David.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know why it’s necessary for to bind the service, and doing a connection to it?

It is not "necessary". That does not mean that arbitrary alternatives are a good idea.

For example, if all your service does is get the `Location`, you should delete the service from your project and just use `LocationManager` directly, as it is unclear what value your service is adding. Do not create services just because the mood strikes you -- have a *very* clear picture of what functionality the service is providing and why it should be a service, versus just a method on an activity somewhere.

For real services that do real things, the service code has to run -- a service typically has no static data members or methods, though one can. In order to get the service to run, something has to call either `startService()` or `bindService()`. Otherwise, `onCreate()` and kin of the service will never be called, just as `onCreate()` and kin of an activity will never be called if the activity is not started.

The choice of whether to use `startService()` (and, later, `stopService()` or `stopSelf()`) or `bindService()` (and, later, `unbindService()`) depends on what the service is doing, how long it is supposed to be doing it, and so forth.